# Using git to pull to production

Tags: php, git, web, deployment, server

I'm going to copy my web-application code to production server with git pull. First I make a SSHFS mount to remote server and then run git pull in the right directory.

If I need to skip production configs etc. I can use .gitigonore.

Very clean and effective so far (compared to manually dragging all changed files from folder to folder)!

But what if I have different directories on remote server? E.g. devel localhost has ~/app/ and ~/app/webroot/ but production server has ~/app/ and ~/public_html/

How to solve these kind of problems?

Comment: I think you can use`.htaccess` file. read up on it.

Comment: well, I might use symlinks, e.g. ~/public_html/js -> ~/app/webroot/js

Answer (score 1):

The generic answer is : `git` is not a deployment tool.

Write a deployment script, and use that script.

You can version the script with your project in your repo, of course.